# Date issue in elasticsearch 2.3.3

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch

After upgrading **elasticsearch** to 2.3.3 i have mapping as:

"**startDate**": {
          "type": "date"
          },

"**endDate**" : {
                    "type": "date"
          }

While writing on ES through hadoop,hadoop job failed with log as:
`org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child : java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while indexing: failure in bulk execution:MapperParsingException[failed to parse [endDate]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: "253402214400000" is malformed at "02214400000"
MapperParsingException[failed to parse [endDate]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: "253402214400000" is malformed at "02214400000"];
MapperParsingException[failed to parse [endDate]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: "253402214400000" is malformed at "02214400000"];
MapperParsingException[failed to parse [endDate]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: "253402214400000" is malformed at "02214400000"];
MapperParsingException[failed to parse [endDate]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: "253402214400000" is malformed at "02214400000"];
MapperParsingException[failed to parse [endDate]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: "253402214400000" is malformed at "02214400000"];`

If i change **endDate** type to long it works. Both **startDate** and **endDate** have same type of value and mapping,**startDate** doesn't have this issue. What might be the reason behind the issue?

Comment: The default date format is `strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis`. Obviously `253402214400000` is in neither of those formats.

Comment: Can elastic search 2.3.3 support date greater than 2286 by our custom mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 13-digit limit for years [has been removed](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/epoch-millis-has-a-maximum-of-13-digits-joda-time-accepts-a-long/50508).

As of ES 5.0.0-alpha3, it is now possible to specify years above 2286 with the `epoch_millis` date format.